# Story with people called "lobsters" who are welded into spacesuits for life?

Tags: story-identification

I read this in 1992-93, maybe... The setting was our solar system, which humanity had explored thoroughly and settled somewhat. There was a group of people who elected to live permanently in space suits, where they were perpetually exposed to space in orbit of a gas giant's moons or something. Because of the exoskeleton-like suits (and maybe they had claws?) this particular group of people were called "lobsters."

Does anyone know the name of this novel/short story or its author?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Possibly [Cicada Queen by Bruce Sterling](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41551).

The *Lobsters* are a group more properly called *Mechanists*:

> I found Wellspring in the swollen bubble of a tubeway bar, discussing a convoluted business deal with a man he introduced as "the Modem." The Modem was a member of a small but vigorous Mechanist sect known in C-K slang as Lobsters. These Lobsters lived exclusively within skin-tight life-support systems, flanged here and there with engines and input-output jacks. The suits were faceless and dull black. The Lobsters looked like chunks of shadow.

The protagonist, Landau (I don't think we ever learn his surname), has to become a Mech to escape some important people he has offended. He ends up staying a Mech and ruling over a group called the Terraform-Kluster.

Comment: Bruce Sterling's hardish sci-fi Shaper/Mechanist universe stories are awesome.

Comment: [Prawns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_9#Plot), [Calamari](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mon_Calamari), [Octopus (ok, missing a tentacle)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrival_(film)#Plot) and Lobster; what a seafood feast we'll have when the aliens arrive!